# Did they have mistcloaks before the Lord Ruler took over?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

In Era 1 of the *Mistborn* series, some Allomancers wear mistcloaks. Vin, Kelsier, and Zane all wear them at times and they seem to have a consistent design. Did they exist before the Lord Ruler?

Comment: Probably not, since Allomancy didn't exist before the Lord Ruler

Comment: @DaveJohnson Allomancy existed before the Lord Ruler, it was just incredibly weak and not at all understood.  It's hinted at if not outright stated that Alendi was using allomancy to find the Well of Ascension.  That said, it also seems like OP is using "allomancer" to mean "mistborn"; which isn't exactly true and is possibly leading to confusion.

Comment: OP, you might want to change "some Allomancers wear mistcloaks" to "some Mistborn wear mistcloaks" since all your examples are of mistborn, and we don't really see mistings wear them (besides Wax in Era 2 I guess).

Answer (score 3):

No. Allomancy was first discovered by the Lord Ruler when he gained the powers at the Well of Ascension. In addition, the Mists didn't exist back then, (technically it did as the Deepness, but no one went out in it), so there wouldn't have even been a point to it.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "discovered", this could be pedantically a bit incorrect.  Alendi was using a seeker ability before Rashek took the power from the well, and there were likely some other weak mistings brought about by the deepness.  Rashek was the one to actually get good access to allomancy and understand it though, so I'm only half-contesting that point, since you could argue that the others were using it but hadn't really "discovered" it.